# How to set an anchor point for CSS img cover

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to have the behavior of CSS image cover, where it fills the container element but doesn't change the proportions of the image; whatever doesn't fit into the viewport of the container element extends beyond the container and is hidden.

However, the way this works in CSS (from how I've used it so far) is it positions it around the center of the image.

I would like to say "set the cover anchor point to x = 150 and y = 375 of the image" type of thing. Wondering how to do that. This way, I could pick a spot on the image and have that be the center point of the cover.

Comment: You mean something like `background-position` for a background image with `background-size: cover`, just when you use `object-fit` on a 'real' image ?

Comment: is it a background image? If it is you could use background-position. (and if it isn't you could always set it as one?)

Comment: it would be impossible to center certain coordinates if the image has a size of "cover" unless you repeat the image. this is simply due to the fact that the image grows in order to fill the whole screen while remaining as small as possible. in other words, its possible to center only a particular subset coordinates. likewise, im not sure you can do this with CSS alone since the image will be changing its dimensions in a "chaotic" fashion (i.e. the images width will grow, and then at a given point its height might grow instead, so on and so forth) as you resize the page.

Comment: the way in which the image increases or decreases in size depends entirely on the proportion of a given image in relation to the changing proportion of the browser. notably, to my understanding, at least one axis will always be centered.

Comment: you could definitely devise an algorithm to determine what area of coordinates are able to be centered. ill post an answer regarding this tomo when i wake up

Comment: im just working on the solution. its pretty damn tricky. but im going to take a break cuz im not thinking straight

Comment: What if we picked say the top right pixel of the image. How would you imagine that working? Would the left side of the container be blank and the background simply start in the middle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `background-position` for a background image or `object-position` for an image with `objec-fit`

you need to calculate the correct value by dividing the coordinate by the image dimension and multiply by 100%

```
background-position: calc(131 / 200 * 100%) calc(66 / 200 * 100%);
/*                        ^^^   ^^^              ^^   ^^^ 
                          |||   |||              ||   |||
                          |||   |||              ||   image height
                          |||   |||          y coordinate
                          |||   image width
                      x coordinate
*/
```

Click on the buttons and you will trigger animations, which show that the focus is on the bird in these images

```js
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'button') {
    document.getElementById(e.target.dataset.id).classList.toggle('animate')
  }
})
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/990/200/200);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: calc(131 / 200 * 100%) calc(66 / 200 * 100%);
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

img {
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
  -o-object-position: calc(131 / 200 * 100%) calc(66 / 200 * 100%);
     object-position: calc(131 / 200 * 100%) calc(66 / 200 * 100%);
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.animate[data-property=width] {
  width: 5px !important;
}
.animate[data-property=height] {
  height: 5px !important;
}
```

```html
<span id="container-1" data-property="width" class="container" style="width:200px; height:100px"></span>
<span id="container-2" data-property="height" class="container" style="width:100px; height:200px"></span>

<img id="image-1" data-property="width" src="https://picsum.photos/id/990/200/200" alt="" style="width:200px; height:100px">
<img id="image-2" data-property="height" src="https://picsum.photos/id/990/200/200" alt="" style="width:100px; height:200px">
<br>
<button data-id="container-1">Animate</button>
<button data-id="container-2">Animate</button>
<button data-id="image-1">Animate</button>
<button data-id="image-2">Animate</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `background-size: cover` extremely limits the quantity of coordinates that can be centered due to how `cover` itself works.

`background-size: cover` enlarges (or decreases the size of) an image in order to always display as much of the image as possible while still being able to cover the whole container.

**Let's visualize some examples:**

[image: Visual Breakdown]

In **Case #1,** the image needs to be enlarged, so that the image's `width` matches the container's `width`.

In **Case #2,** the image needs to be enlarged, so that the image's `height` matches the container's `height`.

In **case #3,** the image needs to be shrunk, so that the image's `height` matches the container's `height`.

[image: Visual Breakdown]

[image: Visual Breakdown]

As you may have noticed, the image will always be centered on one axis already. This means that you can only center the image on the remaining axis. Furthermore, only coordinates that fall between the two red dots or on the red **line,** which is only `1px` wide in reality, can be centered, otherwise the image wouldn't be able to cover the entire container.

**`background: cover` is not sufficient. You need to use JS.**

---

## The Javascript Approach

In order to devise a solution, you need to know...

1. **the inherent dimensions of the image** in order to maintain its proportion.
2. **the dimensions of the container at any given time,** which is a variable.
3. **the coordinates that we want to center,** which is also a variable.

After already spending hours trying to figure this out, I literally just realized that it's completely impractical to do what you want to do because the output image will become infinitely larger the closer the desired center coordinates are to the edge of the original image. It was really tricky figuring out a formula to produce the proper scale of the output image because the scale is also a variable. The only practical way to go about this is to indeed limit what coordinates can be centered by, say, applying a no-go zone around the outer edges of the image like a border (i.e. anything in this area cannot or should not be centered). The width of the so-called border would depend entirely on the resolution of the image.

[image: Self-Imposed Practical Limitations]

Here is what I was working on. You're than welcome to continue where I left off, albeit I have to warn you that the code is a mess right now. I was in the process of wrapping my head around how to properly scale and position the image while maintaining a cover state. A background in math would help big time. Good luck.

```js
const
  srcImg = document.querySelector('#source-image'),
  output = document.querySelector('#output')
let
  srcImgWidth, srcImgHeight

const
test = document.querySelector('#test')

window.onload = ()=>{
  srcImgWidth = srcImg.width
  srcImgHeight = srcImg.height
}

srcImg.onclick = function(e){
  const
   ctrWidth = output.offsetWidth,
    ctrHeight = output.offsetHeight,
    compAxisX = ctrWidth / srcImgWidth,
    compAxisY = ctrHeight / srcImgHeight,
    rect = srcImg.getBoundingClientRect(),
   x = e.clientX - rect.left,
   y = e.clientY - rect.top
  
  // create cover
  if (compAxisX > compAxisY){
    //console.log('width grow/shrink to match width')
    output.style.backgroundSize = `${ctrWidth}px ${ctrWidth / srcImgWidth * srcImgHeight}px`
  } else if (compAxisY > compAxisX) {
    //console.log('height grow/shrink to match height')
    output.style.backgroundSize = `${ctrHeight / srcImgHeight * srcImgWidth}px ${ctrHeight}px`
  } else {
    // square in square ???
    output.style.backgroundSize = `${ctrWidth}px ${ctrHeight}px`
  }
  
  // determine scale of image
  const
    compAxisX1 = ctrWidth / 2 / x,
    compAxisY1 = ctrHeight / 2 / y
  let
    qtrImplicitViewportX,
    qtrImplicitViewportY,
    scale
  
  // cover container with implicit viewport
  if (compAxisX1 > compAxisY1){
    //console.log('width grow/shrink to match width')
    qtrImplicitViewportX = ctrWidth / 2
    qtrImplicitViewportY = ctrWidth / 2 / x * y
    
    //srcImgWidth / x * scale * srcImgWidth + 'px'
    //srcImgHeight / y * scale * srcImgHeight + 'px'
    
    // x / srcImgWidth === qtrImplicitViewportY
    newWidth = qtrImplicitViewportX / (x / srcImgWidth)
    newHeight = qtrImplicitViewportY / (y / srcImgHeight)

    console.log(newWidth, newHeight)
    output.style.backgroundSize = `${newWidth}px ${newHeight}px`
    output.style.backgroundPosition = '0% 100%'
    
  } else if (compAxisY1 > compAxisX1){
    //console.log('height grow/shrink to match height')
    //qtrImplicitViewportX = ctrHeight / 2 / y * x
    qtrImplicitViewportY = ctrHeight / 2
    
    //srcImgWidth / x * scale * srcImgWidth + 'px'
    //srcImgHeight / y * scale * srcImgHeight + 'px'
    
    // x / srcImgWidth === qtrImplicitViewportY
    newWidth = qtrImplicitViewportX / (x / srcImgWidth)
    newHeight = qtrImplicitViewportY / (y / srcImgHeight)

    console.log(newWidth, newHeight)
    output.style.backgroundSize = `${newWidth}px ${newHeight}px`
    output.style.backgroundPosition = '0% 100%'
    
  } else {
    
  }

  test.style.width = newWidth + 'px'
  test.style.height = newHeight + 'px'
  test.style.bottom = output.getBoundingClientRect().bottom
  test.style.left = output.getBoundingClientRect().left
  
}
```

```css
#input-container {
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: grey;
}

#output {
  width: 256px;
  height: 377px;
  resize: both;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid red 3px;
  background-image: url('https://i.postimg.cc/s2PnSDmR/test0.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#test {
  z-index: -1;
  width: 256px;
  height: 377px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  background: orange;
  background-image: url('https://i.postimg.cc/s2PnSDmR/test0.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id='input-container'>  
  <div>Click the Image to Center on Click Point</div>
  <img id='source-image' src='https://i.postimg.cc/s2PnSDmR/test0.png' />
</div>

<div id='output'></div>
<div id='test'></div>
```

Comment: @yunzen its not supposed to work. i abandoned it once i realized how it was absolutely impractical to allow any given coordinates to be centered, but left offered it there in case the OP wants to continue working on it. read my answer

Comment: @yunzen i actually have a new idea of how to achieve it, so ill prolly edit it in the coming week sometime. but im def going to be placing the no-go zone around the edges